# Win Powershell get list of active local users

Tags: powershell, windows-server

I want to get the list of active local users on the windows server. When I do `Get-LocalUser`, I get following output

```
Name               Enabled Description                                                              
----               ------- -----------                                                              
DefaultAccount     False   A user account managed by the system.                                    
Guest              False   Built-in account for guest access to the computer/domain                 
labadmin           True    Built-in account for administering the computer/domain                   
Test               True                                                                             
WDAGUtilityAccount False   A user account managed and used by the system for Windows Defender Application Guard scen...
```

I tried `GetLocalUser -Enabled True` and got following error

```
Get-LocalUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Enabled'.
At line:1 char:79
+ ... ng = New-Object Text.UTF8Encoding $false; Get-LocalUser -Enabled True
+                                                             ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-LocalUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetLocalUserCommandnon-zero return code
```

**What is the correct parameter to filter out the disabled users?**

Comment: `Get-LocalUser | Where-Object { $_.Enabled }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Get-Help -Name "Get-LocalUser"` (also written `help get-localuser`) will show you that the only available parameters are:

```
SYNTAX
    Get-LocalUser [[-Name] <String[]>] [<CommonParameters>]

    Get-LocalUser [[-SID] <SecurityIdentifier[]>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

And there is no parameter to filter on the enabled users. You need to get the results back, then filter afterwards. From the results in your question, the `Enabled` column shows you that the user objects probably have a property called `Enabled` which you can check for the filtering:

```
$users = Get-LocalUser
$enabledUsers = $users | Where-Object { $_.Enabled }
```

If you did not know that, or that did not work because the column name is not exactly the same as the property name, you could run `$users | Get-Member` to see what properties the user objects have, and then look through them for ones to check. Enabled is shown in the result:

```
   TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.LocalUser

Name                   MemberType Definition
----                   ---------- ----------
Clone                  Method     Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.LocalUser Clone()
Equals                 Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode            Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType                Method     type GetType()
ToString               Method     string ToString()
AccountExpires         Property   System.Nullable[datetime] AccountExpires {get;set;}
Description            Property   string Description {get;set;}
Enabled                Property   bool Enabled {get;set;}
FullName               Property   string FullName {get;set;}
LastLogon              Property   System.Nullable[datetime] LastLogon {get;set;}
Name                   Property   string Name {get;set;}
ObjectClass            Property   string ObjectClass {get;set;}
PasswordChangeableDate Property   System.Nullable[datetime] PasswordChangeableDate {get;set;}
PasswordExpires        Property   System.Nullable[datetime] PasswordExpires {get;set;}
PasswordLastSet        Property   System.Nullable[datetime] PasswordLastSet {get;set;}
PasswordRequired       Property   bool PasswordRequired {get;set;}
PrincipalSource        Property   System.Nullable[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PrincipalSource] PrincipalSource {ge...
SID                    Property   System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier SID {get;set;}
UserMayChangePassword  Property   bool UserMayChangePassword {get;set;}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. However, I did it like `Get-LocalUser | Where-Object { $_.Enabled }`